# Does a Mono based application consume more battery (Android)

Tags: c#, java, android, mono

Does a Mono application consume more battery (having to execute more instructions for the same task) compared to a java application developed in eclipse/adt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this article from Xamarin they prove the opposite in which mono touch app consumes less resources than regular java app

http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/05/01/android-in-c-sharp/

Comment: That article is when android itself is running in Mono (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Yes but when you have a MonoForAndroid app, it is running on the same VM as when the whole Android is running in Mono.